# What is the size of this video-card fan?

Tags: graphics-card, fan, dimensions

I cannot find any information on the size of the fan on the video card below (Sapphire Radeon X1650 Pro AGP 512MB). Can someone please tell me the size in millimeters?

I even considered resorting to scaling the image so that the card appears on screen the same size as the card would in real life, then measuring the fan with a ruler, but I cannot find information on the dimensions of the card either. I even thought about doing the same with VGA/DVI connectors, but while I can find pinouts for them, I cannot seem to find their precise physical dimensions. Unfortunately, I don’t think this would work at all because at least part of the fan blades are *inside* the casing, so it is larger than the visible circle.

(The style of blades is amusing; it is unusual and doesn’t look like it would work, but it does, that is, if you blow straight on it, it will spin.)

[image]

Comment: Here's a tip: The distance between the screw receptacles on a standard DVI port is around 37 mm. Based on that, you can calculate the dimensions of the card. Also the length of the whole AGP slot including the dummy rear is around 84 mm.

Comment: Good point. If only I could accurately resize the image by 1-pixel intervals. `:-|` Doh, that won’t work anyway. (Though I may be able to figure out the distance between the fan’s screws.)

Comment: Why bother with that? Use the DVI connector as a measurement unit or even better, becasue o the angle, the AGP pins themselves. There are countless pixel rulers available which will let you count the length in pixels on the AGP slot, count the length in pixels of the whole card and then with a simple equation, you'd get pretty precise information on card length. If the number isn't round, round it up to nearest nice looking number and you'll probably get the correct length. Same for height.

Comment: That won’t work because the fan blades are inside the casing, so I can’t see the full length in the image.

Comment: Also judging by the area it covers on that card and comparing that to fans on some cards I have, I'd say that the fan is most likely a 60 mm fan. The other standard option would be 80 mm, but that looks a bit too large to me.

Comment: i'd note most video card fans seem non standard so replacing them will be a pain. What's the intent for knowing the size of the fan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s got a diameter of 55mm with 39mm between the mounting holes (equilateral triangle, *not* scalene) and is 10mm high:

[image]